# find derivative by direction of gradient

Tags: vector-analysis

The function is:

$$f = \frac{\mathrm{cos}(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{r})}{r^2}$$

so I did the following:

$$(\vec{a},\vec{r}) = (xa_x, ya_y, za_z)$$
$$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$ r^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$$

and ended up with

$$ f =\frac{\mathrm{cos}(xa_x,ya_y,za_z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

what would the derivative be then?

Comment: See definition of derivative for multivariable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the product rule $\nabla (fg)=f\nabla (g)+g\nabla(f)$ and the chain rule $\nabla f(g(\vec r))=f'(g(\vec r))\nabla g(\vec r)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\nabla f&=\nabla \left(\frac{\cos(\vec a\cdot \vec r)}{r^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{r^2}\nabla (\cos(\vec a\cdot \vec r))+\cos(\vec a\cdot \vec r)\nabla \left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{\sin(\vec a\cdot \vec r)}{r^2}\nabla (\vec a\cdot \vec r)-\frac{2\cos(\vec a\cdot \vec r)}{r^3}\nabla (r)\\\\
&=-\vec a\left( \frac{\sin(\vec a\cdot \vec r)}{r^2}\right)-\vec r\left(\frac{2\cos(\vec a\cdot \vec r)}{r^4}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: looks as the most rational way. is there also posibility to use something like $$\frac{du}{dl} = |\vec{\nabla{u}}| =  \ldots $$ ?

Comment: To find the directional derivative, form the inner product of the gradient (which I provided herein) with a unit vector in the direction along which the derivative is taken.